# Поддержка JWT авторизации

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

Делаю Web приложение, которое должно пускать в некоторые свои части пользователя через клиент-приложение. Решил использовать для этого JWT.

Вроде как сделал авторизацию, получение AccessToken и RefreshToken, но вот одного не пойму, допустим мы делаем следующее:

1. Отправляем логин и пароль пользователя на сервер => сервер выдает нам пару токенов.
2. Сохраняем все это дело где то в укромное место клиента (кстати, где оно у WPF?).
3. При использование API - отправляем заголовком наш AccessToken.
4. Как только AccessToken "протухает" - используем RefreshToken => сервер выдает нам снова временный AccessToken.
5. Работаем дальше.
6. Как только опять "протухает" - используем логин и пароль.

Так вот, как я почитал, везде говорят:

> RefreshToken - имеет большое время жизни, и является одноразовым

Собственно и получается, что на этапе 4, мы этот RefreshToken удаляем из базы и больше его не принимаем. Значит при следующем "протухание" AccessToken нам надо отправлять заново логин и пароль и делать все по новой.

Исходя из этого мы получаем то, что клиент вечно будет разлогиниваться и просить доп данные (к примеру 2FA).

Собственно как быть? Как оставить клиент залогининым и не просить пользователя вечно вводить данные для своего аккаунта (2FA)?

Я вижу только 2 варианта:

1. Не использовать 2FA, либо как то переделать авторизацию, что бы 2FA просился только раз на устройстве.
2. Использовать долгий RefreshToken и делать его не одноразовым, но это минус безопасности....

Comment: На этапе 4 сервер вместе с новым AccessToken может прислать и новый RefreshToken тоже, разлогина не будет

Comment: @andreymal тогда при краже Refresh - "злоумышленник" будет иметь постоянную возможность восстанавливать доступ.

Comment: Да, так и будет. Однако JWT и OAuth здесь совершенно ни при чём и это касается любых других способов аутентификации; нужна инвалидация чего-нибудь как-нибудь, когда кража refresh'а обнаружится

Comment: А, например, вот тут в комментариях пишут, что refresh клиенту отдавать вообще не надо... https://habr.com/company/Voximplant/blog/323160/